# Access Dynamic Chart

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to create a chart in Access that works with a drop down.

Meaning that I should be able to select the user from a dropdown to display only his chart: I do not want to write code for it.

```
 WO         User           Diff
3044665 KEITH YASINCHUK 38
3045064 KEITH YASINCHUK 38
3045168 KEITH YASINCHUK 33
3045180 KEITH YASINCHUK 23
3045183 KEITH YASINCHUK 5
3045184 KEITH YASINCHUK 11
3045188 KEITH YASINCHUK 9
3045191 KEITH YASINCHUK 23
3045197 KEITH YASINCHUK 10
```

Comment: Which specific part of the task are you stuck on?

Comment: Have you already created such a chart?  If it is only for display, perhaps you want a form and not a report.  A report could also be used in a Subreport control, and this is really just a matter of preference.  Will you print it?  Or only view it on screen?  These question are important because it effects how you can specify the individual records from the "drop down" (i.e. ComboBox).  Unless you can narrow your requirement or share what you have tried, this question may be too broad for Stack Overflow since tutorials are beyond the scope of answers here.

Comment: If this is a Chart control, chart RowSource would have to be a query that has a filter parameter referencing combobox. Ex: `SELECT M, D, FD, ZD, ZDM FROM GraphProctor WHERE LabNum=[cbxLabNum];` Otherwise perhaps can use Pivot Chart - I never have.

Comment: I can create the chart for one user by using the report design wizard. But since I have multiple users, i want to have a drop down from which i can select the user whom i want to see the graph for.

Comment: Create a form. Put a combo box on the form showing all users. Open the user specific report based on the selected value in your combo box. PS you'll have to write and use code, you can't establish this without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have

- a form with a combo box,
- a report with the chart
- a query to populate the chart.

In the query - add the user-id to the query column in the critera space.
use the format: Forms!formWithcCmboOnIt!nameOfCombo 
then add a button to the form using a macro to open the report.